# Sistema de login no asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu faço para implementar um sistema de login em uma aplicação asp.net MVC. Utilizo o Forms Authentication ou Identity? Andei lendo sobre o Identity e queria ver um exemplo básico do Identity utilizando o template web MVC sem autenticação **No Authentication**. Ou se não, um exemplo **Forms Authentication** no MVC.

Comment: Veja esse artigo que mostra um excelente exemplo de ASP.NET MVC e Identity: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770341/Embedded-Application-Identity-Part-Basic-Identit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770341/Embedded-Application-Identity-Part-Basic-Identit)

Comment: Eduardo, eu queria um exemplo onde não é usado o **Authentication: Individual User Accounts**. Um exemplo básico do zero, sendo usado no **Authentication: No Authentication** do Identity. Ou então um usando o **Forms Authentication** mesmo. Quero fazer um sistema de login básico mesmo, só pra aprendizado.

Comment: @Você quer entender o processo de autenticação ou está aprendendo a usar apenas os frameworks? Já usava web forms no asp.net?

Comment: @Intruso eu quero aprender o processo de autenticação do asp.net MVC, mas sem usar o Individual User Accounts do MVC. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em asp.net MVC, mas queria fazer meu próprio sistema de login. Quando criamos um novo projeto no VS ele nos das as opções no Chance Authentication, e eu quero utilizar o **No Authentication**, porém, não sei como implementar esse sistema de login, registros de contas, igual vem no Identity **Individual User Accounts**. Entendeu? (rs)

Comment: Então comece entendendo os conceitos, depois você passa a entender as ferramentas que pode usar para isso. Do jeito que você está perguntando, está parecendo mais que quer entender como essas ferramentas funcionam. Por exemplo, você pode começar entendendo a diferença entre autenticação e autorização, depois quais os tipos de ferramentas que o .net proporciona para realizar essas atividades. Tenha ciência que o MVC não necessariamente representa o desenvolvimento em asp.net, a velha guarda viveu web forms com arquitetura em camadas e isso ainda é possivel, bem como alguns mecanismos.

Comment: Tem um artigo muito interessante sobre o Identity inclusive com o projeto exemplo para baixar. Um vídeo de quase 3 horas, nele são esclarecidas muitas funcionalidades. No mesmo site tem outros artigos que também ajudam no entendimento. http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/08/asp-net-identity-tutorial-completo/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boa parte das ferramentas que você usava no asp.net com Web Forms estão disponíveis no Asp.net MVC, o Framework evoluiu, mas, não quer dizer que você deixou de ter as outras ferramentas. Logo, você pode implementar um mecanismo de autenticação com base em um repositorio ou serviço, da mesma forma que fazia antes. Um exemplo simplista, seria uma tabela no banco de dados onde você valida um login e senha digitados num form.

É importante destacar que Autorização é diferente de autenticação, o ato de autenticar um usuário é parecido com conferir uma identidade, enquanto que autorizar é permitir a alguem identificado usar um recurso (controlar os urls que alguem pode acessar).

Sendo assim, em um sistema bastante simples, você configuraria o seu Web.config para o tipo de autenticação "Forms", com a url do controller/action que faz o login (o formulario de login) e depois faz um metodo que retorna um booleano conferindo true para login e senha corretos e false para errado.

Amostra de um Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Caso o usuário acerte o login e senha, você autentica ele usando o método:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

Onde username é o login e pronto, você construiu uma aplicação MVC com usando autenticação customizada baseada em forms.

É importante ressaltar que se você controla o login, mas, não restringe o acesso  aos controllers ou actions para usuários autenticados, então você não está fazendo nada. :)

Para restringir o acesso de um Controller ou uma action, você pode usar um atributo "Authorize", como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Essa não é uma boa forma de fazer Autorização, repare que em um dos metodos do controller eu permito apenas ao Admin (fixo no código) acessar, isso deveria ser controlado dinamicamente, até porque, na prática você controla diversos perfis dinamicamente em aplicações do mundo real.

Outro problema é que você tem que lembrar quais áreas (controller/action) são restritas, então as vezes você pode pensar se vale a pena ter uma classe ControllerBase e herdar seus controllers dela, ai você restringe o acesso dessa classe, apesar de que você também pode falhar em herdar dela. Testes automaticos ou revisão de código ajudariam.

Um bom artigo básico sobre Custom Authentication:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Lembre que o método que faz a autenticação customizada é responsabilidade sua, então, você pode usar o repositorio que precisar. Por exemplo, eu trabalhei em um projeto onde usavamos forms para autenticar o usuário no Active Directory da rede, eu usava Forms do mesmo jeito, a diferença era o metodo para autenticar.

Comment: Valeu @Intruso! Ajudou muito.

Comment: só uma ressalva: não, o framework não evoluiu, são dois produtos diferentes que podem coexistir, ou seja, o MVC não é uma evolução do WebForms, ambos são frameworks diferentes que rodam sobre a plataforma ASP.NET.